# RabbitMq rodando num servidor externo

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq

Eu tenho um aplicação web Django que utiliza o celery para as tarefas assíncronas e RabbitMQ para o gerenciamento do broker. Quando ambos estão rodando na mesma máquina, as tarefas são executadas sem problemas, porém a aplicação rodará via internet e está instalada numa instancia EC2 da amazon e o rabbit (por questões de escalabilidade) será instalado em outra máquina. Nos testes realizados com ambos na mesma instância funciona perfeitamente, porém ao tentar conectar ao rabbit em outra instância, ele não executa as tarefas, porém ao executar o celery ele informa que está conectado e pronto. Consultando as informações RabbitMQ, via plugin de interface visual, aparecem as conexões, exchanges e queues gerados.

**O que eu fiz até agora**

> Sei que o RabbitMQ não utiliza o usuário guest para conexões externas, portanto criei um usuário para a conexão, e setei a tag [administrator] para poder acessar o plugin de administração interface visual do RabbitMQ.
>
> Nas configurações da AWS, criei um grupo de segurança e abri as portas 5672, 15672(para o plugin) e 55672.

Se alguém puder me ajudar com o que mais é necessário para que ele distribua as tarefas, sejam tutoriais, vídeos ou pontos da documentação que eu não tenha visto ou entendido.

Comment: Recebi um voto negativo, gostaria de saber o motivo, para que eu possa corrigir numa próxima pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver o problema e resolvi responder a minha própria questão para aqueles que eventualmente caiam aqui através de uma "googlada".

O problema não era com as configurações do rabbitMQ, mas sim do celery no código.

Quando se roda o rabbitmq e o django no mesmo servidor, não é necessário configurações adicionais, além daquelas dos tutoriais. Para aceitar conexões externas e não ter conflitos, é obrigatório a criação de usuário e virtualhost (coisas que eu já tinha feito).

Mas o que realmente resolveu, foi inserir no arquivo__init__.py da mesma pasta onde está localizado o arquivo celery.py o seguinte código:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Com isso, problema resolvido para mim.

Referências:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066316/celery-not-queuing-to-a-remote-broker-adding-tasks-to-a-localhost-instead
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860356/celery-not-queuing-tasks-to-broker-on-remote-server-adds-tasks-to-localhost-ins